# Swing dynamic added Panel not showing

Tags: java, swing, panel, visibility

I'm currently making a java swing GUI with the Netbeans GUI builder. I´m trying to add a bunch of panels dynamically to another panel but they don´t show up. I have already tryed to use repaint(), revalidate(), updateUI() and setvisible(true) from every point that could possibly make sense. I have also tested if the panels are added to the container. They are added, simply don´t show up.

Here is the code adding the panels:

```
    public void setArrangement(LinkedList<PanelScheduleMusician> scheduledPlaces, LinkedList<PanelMusician> assignedMusicians, LinkedList<PanelMusician> freeMusicians) {

    _scheduledPlaces = scheduledPlaces;
    _assignedMusicians = assignedMusicians;
    _freeMusicians = freeMusicians;
}

public void displayPanels() {

    if(_assignedMusicians != null && _assignedMusicians.size() > 0) {
        Iterator<PanelScheduleMusician> iterator = _scheduledPlaces.iterator();
        for(PanelMusician p: _assignedMusicians) {
            iterator.next().setMusician(p);
        }
    }

    if(_scheduledPlaces != null && _scheduledPlaces.size() > 0) {
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panelAssignedMusician);
        panelAssignedMusician.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup parallelGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup sequentialGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

        for(PanelScheduleMusician p: _scheduledPlaces) {
            parallelGroup.addComponent(p);
            sequentialGroup.addComponent(p);
        }
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(parallelGroup);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(sequentialGroup);
    }

    if(_freeMusicians != null && _freeMusicians.size() > 0) {
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panelFreeMusician);
        panelFreeMusician.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup parallelGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup sequentialGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

        for(PanelMusician p: _freeMusicians) {
            parallelGroup.addComponent(p);
            sequentialGroup.addComponent(p);
        }
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(parallelGroup);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(sequentialGroup);
    }
}

public void reset() {
    removeAll();
    initialise();
}

private void initialise() {
    initComponents();
    displayPanels();
    revalidate();
    updateUI();

}
```

And here i create the panels and call the method:

```
    public FormEditDuty() {
    initComponents();

    LinkedList<PanelScheduleMusician> l1 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<PanelMusician> l2 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<PanelMusician> l3 = new LinkedList<>();

    l1.add(new PanelScheduleMusician());
    l1.add(new PanelScheduleMusician());
    l1.add(new PanelScheduleMusician());
    l1.add(new PanelScheduleMusician());

    l3.add(new PanelMusician());
    l3.add(new PanelMusician());
    l3.add(new PanelMusician());

    panelVioline1.setArrangement(l1, l2, l3);
    panelVioline1.reset();
}
```

The way i´m creating the panels is just a test, but it needs to work before i can move on.
If i create and add the panels directly in the same class, it works fine.

Comment: I'm assuming your using the default layout manager (GroupLayout), if so, it has very particular needs when it comes to adding new components. I'd recommend trying a different layout manager, such as GridBagLayour (you can do this in the form designer)

Comment: I still don´t know the reason it didn´t worked this way. But since i removed the creation of the panels and the method call from the constructor and bound them to a button it works.

Comment: randomly applying api rarely solves any problem (f.i. updateUI is _not_ for updating the layout, it's used internally on updating the LAF) With problems like these - that is some basics that normally should work without extra effort - it's best to show an SSCCE that demonstrated the mis-behaviour.